# How to build a .a file in golang

Tags: go

I tried `go build xxx.go`, no file output and no error prompt. I searched and found a solution said should use `go install xxx.go`, got a error :

```
go install: no install location for .go files listed on command line (GOBIN not set)
```

I search this error and found the solution is set the environment variable GOBIN, GOPATH and I did but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved myself. 
The key is: after type `go build xxx.go`, nothing generate, but it's not an error!

I must continue type `go install sourcedir`, the source must inside a directory, then I found the `.a` file in `pkg` folder.

Answer (score 0):

> go install: no install location for .go files listed on command line (GOBIN not set)

Create a `bin` directory under GOPATH parallel to `src`.

**For e.g:**

```
GOPATH=/home/user/go
GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
```

---

**EDIT:** after comment interaction.

Create your go workspace, refer to [workspace doc](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)

For e.g.:

Directory Structure: GOPATH is `/home/user/go`

```
/home/user/go/src/pic-project
  └── pic.go
```

Go to `/home/user/go/src/pic-project`

```
go build pic.go

ls -ltr
-rw-r--r--  1 jeeva  staff       84 Jun 23 23:55 pic.go
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jeeva  staff  1624096 Jun 24 00:02 pic
```

Binary is in the same directory.

Now, let's do `go install`, you can execute install command in following ways.

Inside project directory (binary will be in `$GOPATH/bin` directory)

```
go install
```

OR from anywhere in the terminal-

```
go install pic-project
```

---

Also if you have project with main func and sub packages. Execute `go install <import-path>`, it will produce binary and sub-packages as `.a` files.

```
go install github.com/user/foo
```

You will find `foo.a` under `$GOPATH/pkg/GOOS_GOARCH/github.com/user/foo.a` and binary in the `$GOPATH/bin` directory.

Comment: I have set GOPATH and GOBIN, still nothing generate [](http://codepad.org/qHFB6x91)

Comment: As explained in the answer if you do `go build pic.go` binary will be in the same directory. If you do `go build -i pic.go` binary will be in `$GOPATH/bin` directory.

Comment: More importantly your source should reside inside `$GOPATH/src/<project-name>/...`.

Comment: I `mkdir src` and mv pic.go to ./src, still nothing generate. Try `build -i` got an error: flag provided but not defined: -i
usage: build [-o output] [build flags] [packages]

Build compiles the packages named by the import paths,
along with their dependencies, but it does not install the results .......

Comment: PS, pic.go is from https://github.com/golang/tour/blob/master/pic/pic.go

Comment: I have revised the answer with more details, give it try and let me know.

Comment: I `mkdir pic-project` in `./src` && `mv pic.go pic-project`, then go to pic-project, type `go build pic.go`, still nothing generate nor error prompt. PS, my go version is 1.2.1, does that matter

Comment: I can build a .go file that contain `func main()`, if I rename `func main()`, nothing generate

Comment: I think you're new golang, please start your learning from here https://golang.org/doc/code.html, https://gobyexample.com. I have answered your question, you can accept and start your learning. Good luck.

Comment: No luck so I need help